# Call function only once when element hits top of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I'm trying to call the function `myFunction` only once when one of the elements `#checkPosition` hits the top of the window, but because I have to use `$(window).scroll()` to detect action (scrolling) and at some point scrolled value of `totalScroll` is always bigger than distance of this element to the top `indicatorPosition`, function is called multiple times.

How can I call this function only once?

HTML:

```
<div class="section section--1">
    <p>Section 1</p>
</div>
<div class="section section--2">
    <p>Section 2</p>
    <div id="checkPosition" class="indicator">Check position</div>
    <div id="targetElement" class="target">Target: </div>
</div>
```

CSS (just to get some height):

```
.section {
   min-height: 1000px;
}
```

JS:

```
const indicatorPosition = $('#checkPosition').offset().top;
console.log("indicators initial position:", indicatorPosition);

var myFunction = function(){
  $('#targetElement').append('new text goes here only once. ');
  console.log("call me only once");
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var totalScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (totalScroll > indicatorPosition) {
      myFunction();
    }
});
```

Comment: why, if this value always stays the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way to do it is to use a variable and increment it the moment you call the function then check if the value has changed to see if the function has been called before or not

```js
let indicatorPosition = $('#checkPosition').offset().top;
console.log("indicators initial position:", indicatorPosition);

var myFunction = function(){
  $('#targetElement').append('new text goes here only once. ');
  console.log("call me only once");
}
let check = 1
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var totalScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (totalScroll > indicatorPosition) {
      if(check === 1){
      myFunction();
      check++
      }    
    }
});
```

```css
.section {
   min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section section--1">
    <p>Section 1</p>
</div>
<div class="section section--2">
    <p>Section 2</p>
    <div id="checkPosition" class="indicator">Check position</div>
    <div id="targetElement" class="target">Target: </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. Have you written a comment that I shouldn't been using const for $('#checkPosition').offset().top; ? If so, why?

Comment: @miss.emenems my bad i taught the value change , i did read it as scrollTop()

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'm trying to learn how to properly use const, let and var, so that's why I'm asking :) Thanks, again. I've spend some time today trying different methods to solve this problem and this idea is so simple and works well :)